# jQuery sortable between different unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple unordered lists with a max of 2 list elements per UL.

My dom structure is somewhat like below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="question" data-index="0">
    <li class="answer1" data-index="0">
    <li class="answer2" data-index="0">
  </ul> 

  <ul class="question" data-index="1">
    <li class="answer1" data-index="1">
    <li class="answer2" data-index="1">
  </ul> 

  <ul class="question" data-index="2">
    <li class="answer1" data-index="2">
    <li class="answer2" data-index="2">
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need a way to drag the li elements from one unordered list to another. I'm using jQuery UI and the sortable method like so:

```
$('.wrapper .question').sortable();
```

but obviously only lets me order the li's within it's own unordered list. Would I just call sortable on the list element it self?

EDIT: I should add there can only be 2 list elements per UL

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this jQuery UI Sortable demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists). You can see a demo and view the source code as well so you can implement it as required for your project.

Comment: That works. But my only issue is I can only allow 2 li elements per ul

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this http://www.akchauhan.com/select-content-from-one-list-to-another-using-jquery/

[demo](http://www.akchauhan.com/examples/example01/)